# Extract JSON returned from Servlet in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, servlets

Basically I am trying to extract JSON returned from servlet in JavaScript. I have tested my servlet class already and it did returned some JSON so I guess I no need to post the code for that class. Here is my returned JSON format:

```
[{"mrtpopAmt":"7000","mrtpopX":"17854.99820","mrtpopY":"35056.35003"},{"mrtpopAmt":"6300","mrtpopX":"29798.58427","mrtpopY":"37036.56434"}]
```

And in my JavaScript, I am trying to extract mrtpopAmt, mrtpopX and mrtpopY as one object. Then I will add all object into an array:

```
function getAllMRTPop(time){
var jsonArray;  
var Data = JSON.stringify({ time: time });
$.ajax({
    url: "/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet?action=GetAllMrtPop&time="+ Data + "",
    type: "GET",
    data: Data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data.d);
        console.log(data.d);
        $.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) {
            var jsonObject;
            jsonObject.put("mrtpopAmt", jsondata.mrtpopAmt);
            jsonObject.put("mrtstationX", jsondata.mrtstationX);
            jsonObject.put("mrtstationY", jsondata.mrtstationY);
            alert(jsonObject);
            jsonArray.push(jsonObject);
        });;
    },
    error: function (request, state, errors) {
    }
});
}
```

However, I am getting error message like `Unexpected token: u` at this line:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(data.d);
```

My URL for the servlet contains two parameter, one is action and the other one is time:

```
http://localhost:8080/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet?action=GetAllMrtPop&time=8:00
```

So I wonder am I passing the parameter correctly by passing it in url and as well as data from the code above?

I wonder which part went wrong? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

So I have updated my JavaScript part to this:

```
function getAllMRTPop(time){
var jsonArray = []; 
$.ajax({
    url: "/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet?action=GetAllMrtPop&time=8:00",
    type: "GET",
    data: time,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        //var parsed = JSON.parse(data.d);
        $.each(data, function (i, jsondata) {
            var jsonObject;
            console.log(mrtpopAmt);
            jsonObject.put("mrtpopAmt", jsondata.mrtpopAmt);
            jsonObject.put("mrtstationX", jsondata.mrtstationX);
            jsonObject.put("mrtstationY", jsondata.mrtstationY);
            jsonArray.push(jsonObject);
        });;
    },
    error: function (request, state, errors) {
    }
});
}
```

I tried to print out the mrtpopAmt and it did returned something. But there is an error message:

```
Cannot call method 'put' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying `dataType: "json"`, jQuery already knows you will be getting a JSON response, there is no no need to do `var parsed = JSON.parse(data.d)`

Just do:

`var parsed = data.d`

**Edit:**

```
function getAllMRTPop(time){
    var jsonArray = [];    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet?action=GetAllMrtPop&time=8:00",
        type: "GET",
        data: time,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (i, jsondata) {
                var jsonObject = {};
                jsonObject.mrtpopAmt = jsondata.mrtpopAmt;
                jsonObject.mrtstationX = jsondata.mrtstationX;
                jsonObject.mrtstationY = jsondata.mrtstationY;
                jsonArray.push(jsonObject);
            });;
        },
        error: function (request, state, errors) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: After removed that, I am getting error message like Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at jquery.js:564. Any ideas? I wonder am I doing correctly to pass the parameter to servlet. Let me update the question. :)

Comment: Maybe you just need to use data, could you post the value of data?

Comment: Sorry but when I tried to print out the data, it tells me unexpected end of input. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you are sending the parameters in a wrong way. Are you sure this line `url: "/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet?action=GetAllMrtPop&time="+ Data + ""` is correct? How would you normally call this URL outside jQuery?

Comment: I tested my servlet on browser using this URL: http://localhost:8080/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet?action=GetAllMrtPop&time=8:00. I tried to changed the Data to time directly as suggested by Todd but I am still getting the same error message

Comment: And after changing that, when I try to print out the data, it seems to be like this "[]" then followed by the error message

Comment: [] means an empty array. Could you hardcode the value in your request, just to make sure you are getting the expected result from your servlet?
`url: "/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet?action=GetAllMrtPop&time=8:00"`

Comment: I printed out the data and it was [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] when I hardcode the time and following by error message Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Change this line: `var jsonArray;` to this `var jsonArray = [];`

Comment: Let me update my question again. DO help me take a look when you free :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68452/discussion-between-hugohabel-and-i-was-so-lost).

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that `data.d` is undefined, so you are getting the odd message about unexpected u.

Try this instead:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
```

**Edit** And I think you are probably not formatting your request right:

```
var Data = JSON.stringify({ time: time });
$.ajax({
    url: "/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet?action=GetAllMrtPop&time="+ Data + "",
```

Seems to me that would make the final bit: `&time={"time":"time"}`, so you probably want to look at how you construct `Data`. Maybe just pass `time` directly?

```
url: "/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet?action=GetAllMrtPop&time="+ time + "",
```

Comment: FYI: Edited to provide a more reasonable answer after change to JSON in the question!

Comment: If I changed to this, I am getting error message like unexpected end of input at the same line. So does that means the problem come from my Servlet or Javascript class? I have edited my question for the parameter pass along, am I doing correctly?

Comment: Nope, does not work. I am still getting the same error message at the same line

Comment: Well, sorry man, I tried. Maybe check your server logs or set a breakpoint on the server to make sure the inputs are coming in correctly, and perhaps do an `alert(data)` on the client before parsing to see if anything is amis.